# Background displays over everything else

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why the other Div does not show above the background. I need the background to fit the screen though.

```
<title>The Ultimate Cube World Resource!</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>   

 <div id="container">
 Test
 </div>   

<div style='position:absolute;z-index:0;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%'>
  <img src='img/bfg.jpg' style='width:100%;height:100%' alt='[The Ultimate Resource for      
veryting Cube World! Also, we have a forum and soon a SERVER]' />
</div>


</body>
```

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

#container
{
width:300px;
height:400px;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
z-index:5;
}
```

Comment: I think we'll need more code.  Where is the background? Also, your `#container` needs to have a `position` style to execute `z-index`.  Also remember, you can not manipulate a childs z-index under a parent z-index

Comment: If what you want is a background, you should use a regular CSS rule, like `body {background: url('img/bfg.jpg'); }`

Comment: (You seem to be lacking some `<html><head>` boilerplate here.)

Comment: @Orestes: background-size is [not supported in IE8 and lower](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts) to scale the image to 100%.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz you're right, I didn't realise the point of all this was to fit the bg size.

Answer (score 2):

`z-index` only works on positioned elements. Try adding `position:relative` to your rules.

See this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/BVWXB/)** (try commenting out the position rule)